# JavaScript Countdown Timer not starting [Code Included]

Tags: javascript, countdown

I'm trying to make a countdown timer using JS, obviously.

I think my code is correct, but it does not work.

**Objective of the code:**
The code suppose to show a timer decreasing until it show the content which is `DONE` in the alst line of the code.

**Problem:** I've tried making an HTML page on my local machine and tested it but it didn't work, also I've uploaded it on my website and it does not work too.

Code:

```
<body>

<div 
         id="JSPractice5" 
          style="border-style:dotted; 
          padding:10px; 
          font-size:24px; 
          width:200px; 
          text-align:center;">
Countdown Starting
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var containerID = "JSPractice5";
var number = 100;
var timerID = setInterval("CountdownTimer()",1000);
function CountdownTimer() {
if(number > 1) {
    number--;
    ReplaceContentInContainer(containerID,number); //Mark1
    }
else {
    clearInterval(timerID);
    ReplaceContentInContainer(containerID,'DONE!!');
    }
}
   </script>
</body>
```

If the solution of the problem is easy/stupid and you thought of down voting it, please don't do, because I'm very new to SOF and JS :)

Thanks in Advance guys.

Comment: what is `ReplaceContentInContainer`, it's not in the code?

Comment: What is the ReplaceContentInContainer? Is it defined elsewhere?

Comment: Actually no, I took it from the API.

Comment: i'm sorry, I read it on one of JS forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing

```
function ReplaceContentInContainer(id, content)
{
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = content;
}
```

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/hqbCP/ (time value decreased to 10 in demo code)

Comment: While searching for something to do the job, I read `ReplaceContentInContainer` and no one of the posters mentioned something about the function, since I'm new to JS (never learned, just playing around based on my java) I directly copied it. Thanks Stealthyninja. I will note of this.

Answer (score 1):

Redo your `setInterval` call to specify the function itself, rather than a string containing a call.

See http://jsfiddle.net/2zwbV/2/ for a working example.

Answer (score -1):

```
<body>

<div 
         id="JSPractice5" 
          style="border-style:dotted; 
          padding:10px; 
          font-size:24px; 
          width:200px; 
          text-align:center;">
Countdown Starting
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var containerID = "JSPractice5";
var number = 100;

function CountdownTimer() {
if(number > 1) {
    number--;
    ReplaceContentInContainer(containerID,number);
    }
else {
    clearInterval(timerID);
    ReplaceContentInContainer(containerID,'DONE!!');
    }
}
var timerID = setInterval(CountdownTimer(),1000);
   </script>

</body>
```

First, the timerID should be after CountdownTimer function because if not you are going to call a non existing function, second is that the function CountdownTimer should't be in quotes.

Comment: This line: `setInterval(CountdownTimer(),1000);` won't work. You also don't really understand how `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` [work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval), which is either to `eval()` a string passed in the first argument, or run the function reference passed to it (second being the better practice).

Comment: Jared is correct for the following reason: the first argument to setInterval should be a *reference* to a function, not its result

Comment: Yep, and that means no `()` in `setInterval`.